# Windows Phone - offline/location-off search using GeocodeQuery

Tags: search, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I'm working on a windows phone app where I want to provide a search of the specified place and locate it on Map control. I'm using GeocodeQuery to search for a search term:

```
private void SearchForTerm(String searchTerm)
{
    myGeocodeQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
    myGeocodeQuery.SearchTerm = searchTerm;
    myGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0);
    myGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += GeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
    myGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
}
```

The problem is, that this code works only with location service or wifi turned on. With only location on and wifi off I can't search for every place, even if I have it on my map, but don't have downloaded detailed maps.

For example I can zoom in into Italy and I can see Rome, not streets in detail, but the name of the city is Visible. When I search for "Rome", I'll get 0 results.

This looks like the location service feature is not usable when offline, even with maps in phone. I didn't find any tutorial or example explaining this feature in detail. With [this](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html) example on Nokia developers I have the same problem.

Comment: Look at this [GeocodeQuery - GeoCoordinate property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19139228/1136101).

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone gathers location data from three sources

1. Location Services
2. Network(Data)
3. Sim

And a cumulative of the three sources gives the best result. Obviously, you can get the data from location services alone but data from location services aggregated with the data phone gets from wifi or sim location is supposed to be the most accurate location.

just read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431814%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) once.

also use

```
myGeolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = value;
```

for more accuracy

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to search for a location on map by string using GeocodeQuery, and not to find my location. What I wanted is to do query for "Rome" and get results with geocoordinates.

Comment: what are you using , GeoLocator or a GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Comment: I'm trying to search for a location only using GeocodeQuery. The result is list of geocoordinates. The problem is, that I always get 0 results, so i have no locations to display on map.

Comment: well, if you have wifi or any internet connection turned off, if would be difficult to get accurate location data. Location turned On/Off is just a setting. Wifi is the main player/

Comment: Yes, but how come I can't search for particular location even if I can see it on the map?

Comment: Maps and GeocodeQuery are two very different things, GeocodeQuery is basically a service call to Bing Location provider which would obviously require internet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44333/discussion-between-ladislavm-and-aman-khandelwal)